# Don't understand how to solve error message

Tags: python

I just downloaded python3 (added to PATH) and sublime editor. In sublime editor, a book I'm using tells me to put in "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"], but when I enter it (control B on Windows), I get the following error message -

[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', ........

Comment: try writing : `python "path of file"` in cmd

Comment: Please improve your subject.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put only `python "filename"` in the command line interface to compile your file.

Comment: If it worked for you then please prefer accepting this answer